# sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier all attributes are categorical disable numeric data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Decission Tree classifier with Python3.5 and all of my attributes are categorical but they are already hashed to numbers such as :

```
CityId,ApplianceGroupId,BrandId,StateId,ApplianceTypeId,FCRRepair,FCRRepairFMS,AppointmentIn2Hours,RSR,hasComplaint,hasApplianceExchange,satisfied
1152,1,1,95,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
1152,5,1,95,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
1201,5,1,43,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
882,3,2,69,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

Code :

```
names = ['CityId', 'ApplianceGroupId', 'BrandId','StateId', 'ApplianceTypeId', 'FCRRepair', 'FCRRepairFMS', 'AppointmentIn2Hours', 'RSR', 'hasComplaint', 'hasApplianceExchange', 'satisfied']
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("data_service_onlyenum.csv", names=names,  encoding='utf-8', header=1)
y = targets = labels = dataframe['satisfied'].values
columns  = ['CityId', 'ApplianceGroupId', 'BrandId','StateId', 'ApplianceTypeId', 'FCRRepair', 'FCRRepairFMS', 'AppointmentIn2Hours', 'RSR', 'hasComplaint', 'hasApplianceExchange']
features = dataframe[list(columns)].values

imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
X = imp.fit_transform(features)
#X
plt.plot(dataframe['CityId'].values, y)
plt.show();

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth=100)
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

I think that classifier thinks attributes as numerical and calculates according to that, what is default property for DecissionTreeClassifier or can i disable numeric attributes by setting some propery of that ?

Any help would be appreciated, have a nice day.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly are the "numeric" attributes you want disabled? Why is the output you get above not what you want?

Comment: @not_a_robot, actually all i want is that, set all values in csv file to categorical attribute for decission tree classifier algorithm and don't let algorithm to choose values as numeric, because interval calculation or other things are unnecessary and wrong, as i've already hashed my categorical attributes.

Comment: If you want to turn categorical variables into indicator variables, look into one-hot encoding... [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).